# Angular ternary condition with keydown.space and keydown.tab

Tags: angular, ternary-operator

What I want is to check if a input type is of a particular type only then apply the check of `keydown.space` and `keydown.tab`

What I tried:

```
 <input (keydown.space)="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? $event.preventDefault() : false" (keydown.tab)="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? $event.preventDefault(): false" id="masked-input" [ngClass]="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? 'width-40':''" (input)="textInput()" type="{{locationUi.extra.field.type}}" name="inputOtherAdress" class="form-control" placeholder="{{locationUi.extra.field.placeholder}}"
            [required]="locationUi.enabled" [value]="locationUi.data" (input)="locationUi.data = $event.target.value">
```

Results:

this disables the spaces and tabs on all the input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `false` instead try it with `null` and it should work fine.

```
 <input (keydown.space)="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? $event.preventDefault() : null" (keydown.tab)="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? $event.preventDefault(): null" id="masked-input" [ngClass]="locationUi.location_type=='video' ? 'width-40':''" (input)="textInput()" type="{{locationUi.extra.field.type}}" name="inputOtherAdress" class="form-control" placeholder="{{locationUi.extra.field.placeholder}}"
            [required]="locationUi.enabled" [value]="locationUi.data" (input)="locationUi.data = $event.target.value">
```

Furthermore, a better solution would be to use it through controller.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking it, it probably works if you used `true` instead of `false` in the ternary.

---

However, this should be better handled in the controller anyway. It's quite a bit of logic for the template already and makes the entire thing really hard to read.

```js
public onSpace(event: Event) {
  if (this.locationUi.location_type === "video") {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

and

```
<input (keydown.space)="onSpace($event)" … />
```